# How to club responses from different promises and return it as a single json object to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to get few counts of the number of documents in a mongodb collection based on different conditions.

I am able to get the data and form a single json object but I am unable to send it in response to the client.

In the below code you can see it is my server file (server.js)
where I am doing a GET api call in which I am trying to do multiple database queries and return values in promises.

Rfid is the mongoose model and sub is the empty json object I initialized. I am trying to club data into a single json object at the end,
but I am unable to send the json object(sub) as a response to this get api  call.

It might be the problem  of scope but I am unable to find it out.

Please help me out.

server.js

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req,res){
     var  sub = {};

     var sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4,sub5,sub6,sub7 = {};


    // no of cars entered
    Rfid.find( {entryTime :{$exists :true }})
    .then(function(res,err){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        var length = res.length;
         sub1 = {
             "no_of_cars_entered" : length
        }

         sub  = Object.assign(sub,sub1);

    });

    // no of cars waiting for inspection
    Rfid.find( {entryTime :{$exists :true },inwardInspecStartTime:{$exists:false}})
    .then(function(res,err){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        var length = res.length;
         sub2 = {
            "no_of_cars_waiting_for_inspection" : length
       }

        sub  = Object.assign(sub,sub2);


    });


    //no of cars inspected
    Rfid.find( {inwardInspecEndTime :{$exists :true }})
    .then(function(res,err){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        var length = res.length;
         sub3 = {
            "no_of_cars_inspected" : length
       }
       sub  = Object.assign(sub,sub3);
     });

    //no of cars waiting for invoice (inward REJECTION)
    Rfid.find( {inwardInspecEndTime :{$exists :true },invoiceTime:{$exists:false}})
    .then(function(res,err){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        var length = res.length;
         sub4 = {
            "no_of_cars_waiting_for_invoice" : length
       }
       sub  = Object.assign(sub,sub4);
    });

   // no of cars invoiced
    Rfid.find( {invoiceTime :{$exists :true }})
    .then(function(res,err){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        var length = res.length;
          sub5  = {
            "no_of_cars_invoiced" : length
       }
       sub  = Object.assign(sub,sub5);
    });

    //no of cars waiting for delivery ibnl
    Rfid.find( {invoiceTime :{$exists :true },deliveryInspecStartTime:{$exists :false}})
    .then(function(res,err){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        var length = res.length;
        sub6= {
            "no_of_cars_waiting_for_delivery" : length
       }
       sub  = Object.assign(sub,sub6);       
    });


    // no of cars delivered
    Rfid.find( {deliveryInspecEndTime :{$exists :true }})
    .then(function(res,err){
        if(err) console.log(err);
        var length = res.length;
          sub7 = {
            "no_of_cars_delivered" : length
       }
       sub  = Object.assign(sub,sub7);
       console.log(sub);


    })
    console.log(sub);


});
```

As a result i am getting
OUTPUT I AM GETTING:

```
{ no_of_cars_entered: 6,
  no_of_cars_waiting_for_inspection: 1,
  no_of_cars_inspected: 5,
  no_of_cars_invoiced: 4,
  no_of_cars_waiting_for_invoice: 1,
  no_of_cars_waiting_for_delivery: 0,
  no_of_cars_delivered: 4 }
{}
```

where as i have to get

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
{ no_of_cars_entered: 6,
  no_of_cars_waiting_for_inspection: 1,
  no_of_cars_inspected: 5,
  no_of_cars_invoiced: 4,
  no_of_cars_waiting_for_invoice: 1,
  no_of_cars_waiting_for_delivery: 0,
  no_of_cars_delivered: 4 }

{ no_of_cars_entered: 6,
  no_of_cars_waiting_for_inspection: 1,
  no_of_cars_inspected: 5,
  no_of_cars_invoiced: 4,
  no_of_cars_waiting_for_invoice: 1,
  no_of_cars_waiting_for_delivery: 0,
  no_of_cars_delivered: 4 }
```

Comment: I dont see you ever trying to return a response from your snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you aren't waiting for any of your promises to return before trying to send a response (your snippet doesn't actually show you sending a response back) but when making multiple requests you need to wait for them all to finish and return back before sending a response. Here is an example using ES6 native `Promise` lib.

```js
app.get('/dashboard', function(req,res){
   let promiseArr = [
      Rfid.find( {entryTime :{$exists :true }}),
      Rfid.find( {entryTime :{$exists :true },inwardInspecStartTime:{$exists:false}}),
      Rfid.find( {inwardInspecEndTime :{$exists :true }}),
      Rfid.find( {inwardInspecEndTime :{$exists :true },invoiceTime:{$exists:false}}),
      Rfid.find( {invoiceTime :{$exists :true }}),
      Rfid.find( {invoiceTime :{$exists :true },deliveryInspecStartTime:{$exists :false}}),
      Rfid.find( {deliveryInspecEndTime :{$exists :true }})
   ]
   
   Promise.all(promiseArr)
    .then((resp) => {
      //build your obj here
      // resp[0] = the result of promiseArr[0] etc
      let obj = {};
      //populate obj
      res.send(obj);
      
    }).catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send(err);
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you isaac vidrine for the help, now i am able to solve it.